# Merge Shopify Carts using JS Buy SDK

Tags: javascript, shopify

Background: 
Custom product builder uses JS Buy SDK to add products to the cart using the JS Buy SDK.

The store also has basic products (gift card) etc. These products are added through the "normal" flow of a Shopify cart.

I want to make the carts the same for both flows. I think I should be able to do this by getting by a cookie value and using it in the request to get a checkout.

```
 const checkoutId = getCookie('cart');

 this.props.client.checkout.fetch(checkoutId).then(res => {
   this.setState({
     checkout: res,
  });
```

This does not work. It seems the checkout IDs are different depending on the page. The checkout fetch fails with an invalid id.